# Unable to access the app deployed on minikube cluster by using the url

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-cluster

[image: minikube service]

This the IP I am getting for accessing the application but I am unable to access this app on this url.
[image: connection failed]

This is what I am getting while accessing the url

This is the service file I am using for application.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: villa-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: villa
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31000
  type: NodePort
```

This is the deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: villa.deployment
  labels:
    app: villa
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: villa
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: villa
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: villa
        image: farhan23432/angular
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

This is the inbound rules of the Security group of the instance on which I am running my minikube cluster.
[image: Security group]

[image: versions]

This is the versions of the minikube, docker and kubectl that I am using.

This is the status of the minikube
[image]

Comment: It is not clear but I would suspect the IP address is wrong. 192.68... is a non-public IP range, which is likely what the node can see internally and which is why it tells you that. However, unless the node is on the same network as your browser, there will be a different public IP address for the node that you should use instead.